# Linking PHP/HTML to Javascript using angularJS

Tags: javascript, php, html, angularjs

I want to be able to link a form I have in "details.php" to a javascript file so that I can in turn write the results of a form to an sqlite database. My PHP code is like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Register Tag:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-7">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="singleRegister.RegTag"/>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Register Number:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-7">
        <input type="number" class="form-control" min="1" max="65536" ng-model="singleRegister.Register"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried to link using $scope in the javascript file however it does not seem to be functioning. What would be the correct way of doing this in the javascript file?

Comment: Where is php code?

Comment: @Irfan thats the code im using in my php file to link to the javascript

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. You're aware that PHP runs on the server and Angular runs in the browser?